# how do you extract values between two characters in R?

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract the server name (server101) from this string in R using regular expression:

value between **@** and the following first **period (.)**

```
t<-c("Current CPU load - jvm machine[example network-app_svc_group_mem4]@server101.example.com")
```

I've tried this:

```
gsub('.*\\@(\\d+),(\\d+).*', '\\1', t)
```

this does not seem to be working, any ideas?

Comment: `gsub('@([^.]+)|.', '\\1', t)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with stringr:

```
library(stringr)
str_match(t, ".*@([^\\.]*)\\..*")[2]
#[1] "server101"
```

Comment: Just FYI: `str_match` does not require a full string match. Also, the dot inside a character class is treated as a literal dot and does not need to be escaped. Since there is some value expected after `@`, I think `+` (1 or more occurrences) is more logical than `*` (zero or more occurrences). Thus, I'd use the following pattern with `str_match`:  `"@([^.]+)"`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for the information, much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Since you only expect one match, you may use a simple `sub` here:

```
t <- "Current CPU load - jvm machine[example network-app_svc_group_mem4]@server101.example.com"
sub(".*@([^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", t)
##  => [1] "server101"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/rU1BNo).

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `@` - a `@` char
- `([^.]+)` - Group 1 (`"\\1"`):
- `\\.` - a dot (other chars you need to escape are `$`, `^`, `*`, `(`, `)`, `+`, `[`, `\`, `?`)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible

Here are some alternatives.

You may use the following base R code to extract 1+ characters other than `.` (`[^.]+`) after the first `@`:

```
> t <- "Current CPU load - jvm machine[example network-app_svc_group_mem4]@server101.example.com"
> pattern="@([^.]+)"
> m <- regmatches(t,regexec(pattern,t))
> result = unlist(m)[2]
> result
[1] "server101"
```

With `regexec`, you can access submatches (capturing group contents).

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/FadWnS)

Another way is to use `regmatches`/`regexpr` with a PCRE regex with a `(?<=@)` lookbehind that only checks for the character presence, but does not put the character into the match:

```
> result2 <- regmatches(t, regexpr("(?<=@)[^.]+", t, perl=TRUE))
> result2
[1] "server101"
```

A clean *stringr* approach would be to use the same PCRE regex with `str_extract` (that uses a similar (because it also supports lookarounds), ICU, regex flavor):

```
> library(stringr)
> t<-c("Current CPU load - jvm machine[example network-app_svc_group_mem4]@server101.example.com")
> str_extract(t, "(?<=@)[^.]+")
[1] "server101"
```